# Pass a JavaSscript constructor property into mouseover function & still use d3.select(this)

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, this, onmouseover

I am trying to use `d3.select(this)` and `this.data_` in `this.HandleMouseOver`. I have tried various ways to fix the issue such as converting `.on('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver);` to `.on('mouseover', function(){ this.handleMouseOver(d3.select(this), this.data_); }); // >> error: this.handleMouseOver is not a function` - but no luck so far (yes, I added the inputs on `handleMouseOver(selection,data)`.

Any suggestions on how I can access `d3.select(this)` and `this.data_` in `handleMouseOver()`?

```
class Chart {
    constructor(opts){
        this.data_ = opts.data_;
        this.width_ = opts.width_;
        this.height_ = opts.height_;
        this.draw(); //create the chart
    }

    draw(){
        this.container = svgContainer.append('g')
            .attr('id', 'country-wrapper')
            .attr('width', this.width_)
            .attr('height', this.height_)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
            .on('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver);
            //.on('mouseout', this.handleMouseOut);

    }

    handleMouseOver(){
        var this_ = d3.select(this);
        console.log(this_, this.data_); // this.data_ >> it says it is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to select the global event `d3.event.target` and bind your scope to your event function

```
class Chart {
    constructor(opts){
        this.data_ = opts.data_;
        this.width_ = opts.width_;
        this.height_ = opts.height_;
        this.draw(); //create the chart
    }

    draw(){
        this.container = svgContainer.append('g')
            .attr('id', 'country-wrapper')
            .attr('width', this.width_)
            .attr('height', this.height_)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
            .on('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver.bind(this));
            //.on('mouseout', this.handleMouseOut);

    }

    handleMouseOver() {
        var this_ = d3.select(d3.event.target);
        console.log(this_, this.data_); // this.data_ >> it says it is undefined
   }
}
```

or if you use the modern arrow functions, it does bind your context automatic

```
class Chart {
        constructor(opts){
            this.data_ = opts.data_;
            this.width_ = opts.width_;
            this.height_ = opts.height_;
            this.draw(); //create the chart
        }

        draw(){
            this.container = svgContainer.append('g')
                .attr('id', 'country-wrapper')
                .attr('width', this.width_)
                .attr('height', this.height_)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
                .on('mouseover', this.handleMouseOver);
                //.on('mouseout', this.handleMouseOut);

        }

        handleMouseOver = () => {
            var this_ = d3.select(d3.event.target);
            console.log(this_, this.data_); // this.data_ >> it says it is undefined
       }
    }
```